# How to use "Joins" or "sequelize literal" in nested includes in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, join, sequelize.js

```
const Contentdata = await question.findAll({
    attributes: [`id`, `question`],
    include: [{
      model: option,
      attributes: ['id', 'option','option_es',
        [sequelize.literal('(SELECT case when count(*)=0 then "0" else "1" end FROM `answer` WHERE `userid`=' + userid + ' and `optionid`=options.id)'), 'answer'],
      ],
      on: {
        col1: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('options.questionid'), '=', 
               sequelize.col('question.id')),
      },
      include: [{
        model: focuson,
        attributes: ['id', 'focuson', 'optionid',
             [sequelize.literal('(SELECT case when count(*)=0 then "0" else "1" end FROM 
          `focuson_answer` WHERE `userid`=' + userid + ' and `focusonid`=focusons.id)'), 'answer'],
      
        ],
        
      }]
      
      
    }]
  });
```

In the above example I not able to use focus on object as it gives the error **"column focusons.id"** does not exist, whereas if I pull it out of the nested include it does not show this error. Also if I try to apply to join here it also needs to access the column but it's not.

Comment: Is it a typo? `focusons` vs `focuson`? Since you are using literals there is no way to know what the underlying table names are without guessing...